# Sum of numbers using awk

Tags: awk

I need to make the sums of the numbers from alphanumeric words from a file, USING AWK.

ex: in the file i have :

```
rtig0143
almn3921
ptne2218
```

the result should be

```
sum 8
sum 15
sum 13
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you insist to do it with `awk`:

```
awk -F '' '{ sum = 0; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) sum += $i; print "sum " sum }' file
```

Comment: Note that it assumes `gawk`, `mawk` or busybox `awk`, that is the `awk` typically found on Linux-based OSes, but generally not others.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Right, traditional `(n)awk` doesn't allow an empty `FS`.

Answer (score 2):

POSIXly:

```
awk '{for (i = sum = 0; i++ < length;) s += substr($0, i, 1); print "sum", s}'
```

Same principle as [Sato Katsura's answer](/a/364209/): we're adding up all the characters on the line; when converted from string to number, the characters that are decimal digits are converted to the value of the digit, while the others are converted to 0.

Removing the non-digit characters (with `gsub(/[^0-9]/, "")` or preprocessing with `tr -cd '0-9\n'`) beforehand might improve performances.

Answer (score 1):

***Python*** 3.x approach (just the alternative solution):

`sum_digits.py` script:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        print("sum", sum(int(d) for d in l if d.isdigit()))
```

***Usage***:

```
python3 sum_digits.py yourfile
```

The output:

```
sum 8
sum 15
sum 13
```